Move quote / text further to the middle of the page
I am trying to move a quote more to the middle of the page, but I don't seem to get it right. Here is my code:
\thispagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}\selectfont % Set the line spacing to 2
\hskip 2.5cm
\vskip 2.5cm
\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
\noindent
\textsl{\Large{~~~~~``Η αστρονοµία αναγκάζει την ψυχή να κοιτάξει ψηλά,\\~~~~~και µας οδηγεί από αυτόν τον κόσµο σε έναν άλλο.''}}\\ ~~~~~\large{ΠΛΑΤΩΝΑΣ}
\end{otherlanguage}\\~\\~\\
\textsl{\Large{~~~~~`Astronomy compels the soul to look upwards \\~~~~~and leads us from this world to another.'}}\\ ~~~~~\large{PLATO}\\
\clearpage
\normalsize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\selectfont % Set the line spacing to 1.5

And here is the result:

I tried playing with hskip and hoffset but nothing seemed to work. I am using these commands to reshape my document.
\newgeometry{left=35mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, includeheadfoot}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\selectfont % Set the line spacing to 1.5

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!!

I tried it but it did not work for some reason... Thanks for your input though!

Do you mean closer to the center  horizontally or vertically?

I meant horizontally (i.e. more space to the left)

The quotation environment uses \leftmargini to set both the left and right margins (unless it is nested in another \list).

I couldn't get the greek to show on my setup.  (Not my problem.)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment aid

\AddToHook{env/quotation/before}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{2cm}}% overkill

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}\selectfont % Set the line spacing to 2

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\begin{quotation}\noindent
\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
\Large ``Η αστρονοµία αναγκάζει την ψυχή να κοιτάξει ψηλά, και µας οδηγεί από αυτόν τον κόσµο σε έναν άλλο.''\\
\large ΠΛΑΤΩΝΑΣ
\end{otherlanguage}\end{quotation}

\begin{quotation}\noindent
\textsl{\Large Astronomy compels the soul to look upwards and leads us from this world to another.}\\ \large{PLATO}\\
\end{quotation}

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\clearpage
\normalsize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\selectfont % Set the line spacing to 1.5

\end{document}


I ended up using a minipage. That's my solution around the problem:
\thispagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\selectfont % Set the line spacing to 1.5

\raisebox{-5 cm}{
\begin{minipage}[c]{15cm}
\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
    \noindent
    \textbf{\Large{``Η αστρονοµία αναγκάζει την ψυχή να κοιτάξει ψηλά,\\ και µας οδηγεί από αυτόν τον κόσµο σε έναν άλλο.''}}\\  --- \large{ΠΛΑΤΩΝΑΣ}
\end{otherlanguage}\\~\\
    \textbf{\Large{`Astronomy compels the soul to look upwards \\ and leads us from this world to another.'}}\\ --- \large{PLATO}\\~\\~\\~\\
    \LARGE {\textit{Dedicated to my mum and dad.}}
\end{minipage} }
%
\pagebreak
\normalsize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\selectfont % Set the line spacing to 1.5


There is a command called \vspace{length} that create a vertical space of the specified length. When combine with the \stretch{number} command, you'll get what you want.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}\selectfont % Set the line spacing to 2

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
\noindent
\textsl{\Large{~~~~~``Η αστρονοµία αναγκάζει την ψυχή να κοιτάξει ψηλά,\\~~~~~και µας οδηγεί από αυτόν τον κόσµο σε έναν άλλο.''}}\\ ~~~~~\large{ΠΛΑΤΩΝΑΣ}
\end{otherlanguage}\\~\\~\\
\textsl{\Large{~~~~~`Astronomy compels the soul to look upwards \\~~~~~and leads us from this world to another.'}}\\ ~~~~~\large{PLATO}\\

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\clearpage
\normalsize
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}\selectfont % Set the line spacing to 1.5

\end{document}

The \stretch{} command add the number in all the commands (here it is a sum of 2) and split the remaing space accordingly. Here, it create two equal rubber length.
